# lsb-base-logging script and "INITOUTPUT" variable in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I had some troubles installing Mysql server on an ubuntu machine. after some searching I found the init script of Mysql (/etc/init.d/mysql) tries calling the "/etc/lsb-base-logging.sh" shell script, which in 4 of its lines checks for value of the variable "INITOUTPUT" and this variable is not defined.

I just commented those 4 lines and everything worked fine. I checked my laptop which is using Fedora 10, and I did not have the "lsb-base-logging.sh" script at all. does anybody know what specific task this script does in the system, and why it is using a variable which is not defined? and what that variable is actually for?

**update**
I'm attaching the script in here. file: /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh

```
# Default init script logging functions suitable for Ubuntu.
# See /lib/lsb/init-functions for usage help.
# edited by Farzad Ghanei lines 84, 114, 136, 156 are commented to fix mysql server start

. /etc/default/rcS

log_use_usplash () {
    if [ "${loop:-n}" = y ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    type usplash_write >/dev/null 2>&1
}

log_to_console () {
    [ "${loop:-n}" != y ] || return 0
    [ "${QUIET:-no}" != yes ] || return 0

    # Only output to the console when we're given /dev/null
    stdin=`readlink /proc/self/fd/0`
    [ "${stdin#/dev/null}" != "$stdin" ] || return 0

    func=$1
    shift

    loop=y $func "$@" </dev/console >/dev/console 2>&1 || true
}

log_success_msg () {
    if log_use_usplash; then
        usplash_write "STATUS $*" || true
    fi

    log_to_console log_success_msg "$@"

    echo " * $@"
}

log_failure_msg () {
    if log_use_usplash; then
        usplash_write "STATUS $*" || true
    fi

    log_to_console log_failure_msg "$@"

    if log_use_fancy_output; then
        RED=`$TPUT setaf 1`
        NORMAL=`$TPUT op`
        echo " $RED*$NORMAL $@"
    else
        echo " * $@"
    fi
}

log_warning_msg () {
    if log_use_usplash; then
        usplash_write "STATUS $*" || true
    fi

    log_to_console log_warning_msg "$@"

    if log_use_fancy_output; then
        YELLOW=`$TPUT setaf 3`
        NORMAL=`$TPUT op`
        echo " $YELLOW*$NORMAL $@"
    else
        echo " * $@"
    fi
}

log_begin_msg () {
    log_daemon_msg "$1"
}

log_daemon_msg () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    if log_use_usplash; then
        usplash_write "TEXT $*" || true
    fi

    log_to_console log_daemon_msg "$@"

#    if [ "$INITOUTPUT" = "yes" ]; then
        if log_use_fancy_output && $TPUT xenl >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            COLS=`$TPUT cols`
            if [ "$COLS" ] && [ "$COLS" -gt 6 ]; then
                COL=`$EXPR $COLS - 7`
            else
            COLS=80
                COL=73
            fi
            # We leave the cursor `hanging' about-to-wrap (see terminfo(5)
            # xenl, which is approximately right). That way if the script
            # prints anything then we will be on the next line and not
            # overwrite part of the message.

            # Previous versions of this code attempted to colour-code the
            # asterisk but this can't be done reliably because in practice
            # init scripts sometimes print messages even when they succeed
            # and we won't be able to reliably know where the colourful
            # asterisk ought to go.

            printf " * $*       "
            # Enough trailing spaces for ` [fail]' to fit in; if the message
            # is too long it wraps here rather than later, which is what we
            # want.
            $TPUT hpa `$EXPR $COLS - 1`
            printf ' '
        else
            echo " * $@"
            COL=
        fi
#    fi
}

log_progress_msg () {
    :
}

log_end_msg () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    if log_use_usplash; then
        if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
            usplash_write "SUCCESS OK" || true
        else
            usplash_write "FAILURE failed" || true
        fi
    fi

    log_to_console log_end_msg "$@"

#    if [ "$INITOUTPUT" = "yes" ]; then
        if [ "$COL" ] && [ -x "$TPUT" ]; then
            printf "\r"
            $TPUT hpa $COL
            if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "[ OK ]"
            else
                printf '['
                $TPUT setaf 1 # red
                printf fail
                $TPUT op # normal
                echo ']'
            fi
        else
            if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "   ...done."
            else
                echo "   ...fail!"
            fi
        fi
#    fi

    return $1
}

log_action_msg () {
    if log_use_usplash; then
        usplash_write "TEXT $*" || true
    fi

    log_to_console log_action_msg "$@"

    echo " * $@"
}

log_action_begin_msg () {
    log_daemon_msg "$@..."
}

log_action_cont_msg () {
    log_daemon_msg "$@..."
}

log_action_end_msg () {
    # In the future this may do something with $2 as well.
    log_end_msg "$1" || true
}
```

Comment: I don't have any references to "INITOUTPUT" in my "/etc/lsb-base-logging.sh". Can you post some examples of how it's used?

Comment: sure. I attached the changed file in here. I had to comment 4 lines (2 if statements and 2 if closings) to resolve the issue.

Comment: This seems to be a known problem on Ubuntu Netbook Remix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `/etc/lsb-base-logging.sh` is identical to yours except for the lines related to the "INITOUTPUT" variable and the `. /etc/default/rcS` line near the beginning.

It seems that rather than comment out the lines, you should add `INITOUTPUT=yes` in your `/etc/default/rcS` file. The variable is intended to control whether some logging output is performed during system startup.

As far as the purpose of the script, there's this from `/usr/share/doc/lsb-base/README.Debian.gz`:

```
The Debian lsb-base package provides a series of logging functions to
permit simplified logging of init script actions.  These functions are
specific to Debian and (in some cases) other derived distributions.
```

What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: the OS is HP Mi, a customized Ubuntu 8 that runs on HP Mini netbooks. I'm not a bash scripter but I think I found what you meant. thanks for the detailed descriptions.